# Invertible linear map, kernel-image theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb R$ vector space and let $T: V \to V$ be a linear map of rank 1.

a) Show that there exists a unique real number $c$ such that $T^2 = cT$

b) Show that if $c \neq 1$ then $I -T$ has an inverse where $I$ denotes the identity map.

I need help with this problem, please. Here are my thoughts: The rank of $T$ is the dimension of the image, thus the image of $T$ has dimension 1. Since domain $V$ is finite-dimensional, $Ker(T)$ will have a dimension of $n-1$. Let $\vec w_0 \in Im(T)$ be a basis for the image, $T(\vec v_0) = \vec w_0$. And we have $T^2= T \circ T (\vec v) = T(T(\vec v))= cT(\vec v_0)$.
For part b): I want to show that $ker(I - T) = \{\vec 0 \}$ and then by the kernel-image theorem the dimension of domain and image will be 1, thus $I -T$ has an inverse.

Comment: We have $Tw_0=cw_0.$ Then $T^2=cT.$ For $c\neq 1$ we get  $(I-T)(I-(c-1)^{-1}T)=I.$

Answer (score 1):

For part $(b)$

$T^2=cT$ implies $T$ has only two eigenvalues $0$ and $c$.(why?)

If $c\neq 1$, $I-T$ will never have eigenvalue $0$.(why?)

We're done then.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0\neq w_0\in {\rm Im}\,T.$ Then $$Tw_0=cw_0$$ for some $c.$ For $v\in V$ we have $Tv=d_vw_0.$ Therefore $$T^2v=d_vcw_0=cTv$$ i.e. $T^2=cT.$ If $c\neq 1$ then $$(I-T)\left (I-{1\over c-1}T\right )=I$$ Hence $I-T$ is invertible.